# Here, it is not immutable because key & value of HashMap(field value) can be changed. Please suggest the solution to make it true Immutable class

Tags: collections, hashmap, immutability

```
import java.util.*;

final class MyImmutableClass {
    private final HashMap h = null;

    public MyImmutableClass(HashMap h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    public HashMap getH() {
        return h;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expose an unmodifiable map from your class:

```
import java.util.*;

final class MyImmutableClass {
    private final HashMap h = null;
    private Map<String, String> noModMap;

    public MyImmutableClass(HashMap h) {
        this.h = h;
        noModMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(h);
    }

    public Map getH() {
        return noModMap;
    }
}
```

The map returned by `getH()` would basically be a read-only view into the underlying mapped passed in during class construction.  From the JavaDoc for [`Collections#unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)):

> Query operations on the returned map "read through" to the specified map, and attempts to modify the returned map, whether direct or via its collection views, result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

So, anyone trying to alter the map view would throw an exception, and the underlying initial map cannot be changed from the outside.